# Tomcat Setup Error when changing port

Tags: tomcat

I'm setting up Tomcat server on my Mac. 
With the default port 8080 , the tomcat server started fine. But when i changed the port to 9999, I get the below error

```
 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester fatalError
SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 70 column 21: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "port".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "port".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
```

Below is my server.xml file

```
  <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port=“9999” protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->
```

Use the following command to run tomcat

./catalina.sh run

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is easy ... please open this file in Notepad only .. there is a difference between the quote that u have used and the quote that Tomcat expects.

**What it wants is this  `port="9999"`
And used a different quote `port=“9999”` Please see the difference in quote.**

Comment: There is a difference in the ASCII value of the two quotes so the SAX parser throws an Exception.
This has happened because the opened the Servers.xml file in an advanced Text Editor. so The Text editor add a Fancy looking quote. Or Just copy paste the correct quote from my answer.